# Exclude false objects from JSON response

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've searched around so I apologize if this is something that's been asked somewhere, I could be searching with incorrect terms.

I have a method called self.hidden on a model called activity that takes a boolean. The purpose is to display only activities that are not hidden to the client instead of returning both true/false. I'm trying to do this without creating a new route if possible and just use the existing activities route.

Comment: what is the question? be more clear..

Comment: displayed_items = my_collection.select{|item| item.hidden == false}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a class method `visible`to return only the records which should be visible:

```
def self.visible
  self.where(hidden: false)
end
```

So you can call ClassName.visible to get all visible objects

Comment: Awesome thank you. You and Dillon are both correct but I was missing this.

Answer (score 0):

Using akz92's answer you could do something like the following in your controller:

```rb
class MyController < AnotherController
  def index
    render json: Activity.visible
  end
end
```

Also, if you needed additional scope/conditions you can chain them:

```rb
class MyController < AnotherController
  def index
    render json: activities.visible
  end

  private

  def activities
    Activity.where(description: 'Added by Admin') 
  end
end
```

Comment: Question Dillion, because this is class method wouldnt it be: `render json: Activity.visible` ?

Comment: Both are correct. My example shows the method being used with additional scopes and conditions. If you want every single activity except for hidden ones you are able to just say `render json: Activity.visible`